# PHP variables in php.ini auto_prepend_file are not readable in Slim Framework class

Tags: php, slim

I have a web application which is built in PHP 5.5. A new application has been added to it (in a sub-directory) which is built in Slim Framework v3.

The application is running in an environment whereby *any* PHP script that is executed has a file, `config.php`, included automatically using the `auto_prepend_file` directive in php.ini.

This is equivalent to having the following in *all* scripts, as far as I understand, but without the need to manually write `require_once 'config.php'` every time:

```
<?php
    require_once 'config.php';
    // Script starts here
?>
```

`config.php` contains a number of configuration settings; some of these are set using PHP's `define` method, (e.g. `define('FOO', 'bar')`) and others are normal PHP variables (e.g. `$ASSETS_VER = '1.0'`);

Whenever we run PHP scripts *that are not part of the Slim application* **all** of the variables in `config.php` can be read. For example...

```
<?php
// myscript.php
echo FOO;
echo $ASSETS_VER;
?>
```

...will output whatever is in the config file ('bar' and '1.0' respectively).

#### The problem

However in the part of the application which uses Slim Framework - we can only read things from `config.php` which have been set using `define()`, whereas regular variables are undefined. So in the example above `echo FOO` will produce 'bar' whereas `echo $ASSETS_VER` will not produce anything.

I'm not sure if this is something to do with how Slim Framework works, but wondered if anyone knows why this is the case, and how to fix it?

Comment: Are you setting global variables, and trying to access them in a function or a method?

Comment: If you run `phpinfo` within any of the pages within the Slim Framework, is the same `PHP.ini` and `auto_prepend_file` listed?

Comment: I think it's about the scope of your variable. Constants in the global scope are global too, variables aren't. Unless you define it.

Comment: Ok, it is indeed to do with the scope of the variables. So are there any practical methods to pass those in config.php into my Slim classes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`PHP` documentation [on variables scopes](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php) reads: "For the most part all PHP variables only have a single scope. This single scope spans included and required files as well. ... within user-defined functions a local function scope is introduced. Any variable used inside a function is by default limited to the local function scope."

It seems that your "PHP scripts that are not part of the Slim application" use data from `config.php` only from code in global scope, i.e. from code  that is not located inside method or function. So it sees both `PHP` constants and variables from `config.php` that are also in global scope.

Code that uses frameworks, such as `Slim Framework` usually is located in some kind of callback method or function that is called by framework code (i.e. it is in local scope). So your code sees global scope `PHP` constants (that are visible from local scope), but doesn't see global scope `PHP` variables (that are replaced by new-created local scope empty variables with the same names).

In order to use them you can declare them before using with keyword `global`, like this:

```
...
global $ASSETS_VER;
echo $ASSETS_VER;
...
```